# Android - Paygate Payment Gateway Redirect Error when payment success

Tags: java, android, kotlin

We are trying use Paygate with PayHost. We are receiving null map from the Paygate call back. As per checking on notify and success URL. We are receiving data from the PayGate. But didn't get response from the

When we are using paygate testing data that time we are receiving response on map but when we are switching data from live that time we are facing this issue.

We have implemented SSL also crate Notify & Success URL as per PayGate Demo Source Code.

```
 CardPaymentActivity.attachCallback(new CardPaymentActivity.onFinishedTransaction() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFinish(HashMap<String, String> map) {
                                    if (map == null) {
                                        payGateResponseCallback.onSuccess(data, res);
                                    } else {
                                        String csString = payGateId.concat(map.get("PAY_REQUEST_ID")).concat(map.get("TRANSACTION_STATUS")).concat(order.getMerchantOrderId()).concat(password);
                                        String checksum = new String(Hex.encodeHex(DigestUtils.md5(csString)));
                                        if (checksum.equalsIgnoreCase(map.get("CHECKSUM"))) {
                                            payGateResponseCallback.onSuccess(data, "1");
                                        } else {
                                            payGateResponseCallback.onSuccess(data, "0");
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            });
```

On Finish Call Back we are receiving null map from Paygate

Source code is available in this link - https://github.com/PayGate/sample-code-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/appinlet/payhost/Api/WebPaymentApi.java